# My custom settings app fails to find com.android.i18n library

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to build a clone of the Android system default Settings app on Android 13 r31. I've done it before on Android 9 and 10 successfully. The difference between the system default app and its clone is just in the name. E.g. my app is MySettings and the system settings app is just Settings. I just copy paste the settings folder in packages/apps in the same place and rename the new folder to MySettings and then edit the name from inside in all the Android.bp files.
After editing the 'names' in the Android.bp(used to have .mk extension) files when I use the command: `mmm packages/apps/MySettings`

I get these errors:

```
packages/apps/MySettings/src/com/android/settings/datetime/timezone/model/FilteredCountryTimeZones.java:22: error: symbol not found com.android.i18n.timezone.CountryTimeZo
nes
import com.android.i18n.timezone.CountryTimeZones;
       ^
packages/apps/MySettings/src/com/android/settings/datetime/timezone/model/FilteredCountryTimeZones.java:38: error: could not resolve CountryTimeZones
    public FilteredCountryTimeZones(CountryTimeZones countryTimeZones) {
                                    ^
packages/apps/MySettings/src/com/android/settings/datetime/timezone/model/FilteredCountryTimeZones.java:58: error: could not resolve CountryTimeZones
    public CountryTimeZones getCountryTimeZones() {
           ^
packages/apps/MySettings/src/com/android/settings/datetime/timezone/model/FilteredCountryTimeZones.java:34: error: could not resolve CountryTimeZones
    private final CountryTimeZones mCountryTimeZones;
                  ^
packages/apps/MySettings/src/com/android/settings/datetime/timezone/model/TimeZoneData.java:22: error: symbol not found com.android.i18n.timezone.CountryZonesFinder
import com.android.i18n.timezone.CountryZonesFinder;
       ^
packages/apps/MySettings/src/com/android/settings/datetime/timezone/model/TimeZoneData.java:56: error: could not resolve CountryZonesFinder
    public TimeZoneData(CountryZonesFinder countryZonesFinder) {
                        ^
packages/apps/MySettings/src/com/android/settings/datetime/timezone/model/TimeZoneData.java:42: error: could not resolve CountryZonesFinder
    private final CountryZonesFinder mCountryZonesFinder;
                  ^
packages/apps/MySettings/src/com/android/settings/datetime/timezone/model/TimeZoneData.java:21: error: package com.android.i18n.timezone does not exist
import com.android.i18n.timezone.CountryTimeZones;
                                ^
packages/apps/MySettings/src/com/android/settings/datetime/timezone/model/TimeZoneData.java:22: error: package com.android.i18n.timezone does not exist
import com.android.i18n.timezone.CountryZonesFinder;
                                ^
packages/apps/MySettings/src/com/android/settings/datetime/timezone/model/TimeZoneData.java:23: error: package com.android.i18n.timezone does not exist
import com.android.i18n.timezone.TimeZoneFinder;
                                ^
packages/apps/MySettings/src/com/android/settings/datetime/timezone/model/TimeZoneData.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
    private final CountryZonesFinder mCountryZonesFinder;
                  ^
  symbol:   class CountryZonesFinder
  location: class TimeZoneData
packages/apps/MySettings/src/com/android/settings/datetime/timezone/model/TimeZoneData.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
    public TimeZoneData(CountryZonesFinder countryZonesFinder) {
                        ^
  symbol:   class CountryZonesFinder
  location: class TimeZoneData
packages/apps/MySettings/src/com/android/settings/datetime/timezone/model/FilteredCountryTimeZones.java:22: error: package com.android.i18n.timezone does not exist
import com.android.i18n.timezone.CountryTimeZones;
                                ^
packages/apps/MySettings/src/com/android/settings/datetime/timezone/model/FilteredCountryTimeZones.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
    private final CountryTimeZones mCountryTimeZones;
                  ^
  symbol:   class CountryTimeZones
  location: class FilteredCountryTimeZones
packages/apps/MySettings/src/com/android/settings/datetime/timezone/model/FilteredCountryTimeZones.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
    public FilteredCountryTimeZones(CountryTimeZones countryTimeZones) {
                                    ^
  symbol:   class CountryTimeZones
  location: class FilteredCountryTimeZones
packages/apps/MySettings/src/com/android/settings/datetime/timezone/model/FilteredCountryTimeZones.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
    public CountryTimeZones getCountryTimeZones() {
           ^
  symbol:   class CountryTimeZones
  location: class FilteredCountryTimeZones

9 errors
2 warnings
15:06:24 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (05:13 (mm:ss)) ####
```

From what I can understand, my app can't seem to access the com.android.i18n library. The i18n files can be found deep in the ext directory. When I build the system settings, it can access the i18n library, but my app can't. Why is that? And how can I get passed this problem?

I could not find any solutions to this. I followed all the steps required to build a clone of settings, just as I have successfully done before several times on lower android versions like giving it permission when the package name was different.